# Using App Service Certificate with Service Fabric

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I purchase an App Service Certificate, and when I connected it up with the Service Fabric I got the below deployment error.
I can find documentation to upload a PFX in JSON format, but I cannot find anything about converting the certificate into JSON format.  It seems you can't even export the certificate, is this the case?
How do I remedy this?

```
{
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "CertificateImproperlyFormatted",
        "message": "The data retrieved from https://XXXX.vault.azure.net/secretsYYY/ZZZ is not deserializable into JSON."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: did you see this documentation? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-creation-via-arm/

Comment: I did, but that is only information if you have your own SSL certification unfortunately.

Comment: The closest I can get is downloading the certificate, but I still need to know the password, using: $secretRetrieved = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'vault' -Name 'name'
$pfxBytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($secretRetrieved.SecretValueText)
[io.file]::WriteAllBytes("D:\Development\Tools\Service-Fabric-master\certificate.pfx", $pfxBytes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok figured it out, as per my comments you can actually download the certificate via the Vault and it doesn't have a password at all. So you can then use it how you want.

```
$secretRetrieved = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'vault' -Name 'name'
$pfxBytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($secretRetrieved.SecretValueText)
[io.file]::WriteAllBytes("D:\Development\Tools\Service-Fabric-master\certificate.pfx", $pfxBytes)
```